# Monkey with Coins Killing

Tags: calculation-puzzle

10 people can share a bucket of coins equally. A monkey steals one coin. The number of coins remaining is therefore 1 less than would allow them to be shared out equally.

One person after another tries to take the coin from the monkey -- but each time, the monkey kills them. Each time a person dies, the number of coins is still 1 less than would allow the remaining people to share them out equally, until we are left with just one person who wisely leaves the monkey alone and takes away ... *how many coins*?

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to, for instance, this puzzle: [N pirates steal their share of bananas to the benefit of a monkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/376/n-pirates-steal-their-share-of-bananas-to-the-benefit-of-a-monkey?rq=1).

> We're looking for a number that's 1 less than a multiple of 2,3,4,...,10. In other words, when we add 1 we get a number that's a multiple of all those numbers. Equivalently, that's a multiple of their LCM, which is 8x9x5x7=2520.

Therefore

> the number of coins in the bucket was one less than some (positive) multiple of 2520. The smallest possible number is 2519.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> # of coins = $2519+2520x$.

so the minimum number of coins is

> $2519$

I have used a simple code you can run by yourself: http://rextester.com/AKQ5063